# I want to send multi-media file in twitter post from flutter app

Tags: flutter, post, twitter, social-media, socialshare

I want to send multi-media file in twitter post from flutter app, How can I do it. As per my flow, user will create a post and send it on twitter. I am able to open the twitter app in device but when I do the post, only text is getting posted and it's not posting the multi-media file. I need help with it.

I am using "social_share: ^2.3.1" package and tried with "appinio_social_share: ^0.2.6". Didn't get the result

I tried
"social_share: ^2.3.1" package
"appinio_social_share: ^0.2.6".

Didn't get the result. It only sending text in post